# How can i convert (-0.143704570332567-1.2618680524722614j) to something sklearn fit method can use?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have to convert a column that contains this type of values:  `(-0.143704570332567-1.2618680524722614j)` to a something that `fit` method from `sklearn` can use.

I get this error:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(-0.17904283086526662-1.0019223461852513j)'

when i use: `self.model.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)`

Comment: That is a complex number. How do you suppose to use it? Where did it come from? Nobody but you can answer that for you.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa the value i got is the first component of FFT function. generated it using: self.vector_of_fft_components = np.fft.fft(self.IAT_vector, n = 11) and wrote into a csv with outstring = '\t'.join([          
            str(flow.vector_of_fft_components[1])])          
f.write(outstring+'\n').

I need to use this value for my logistic-regression classifier, but the "fit" method can't work with it like this.

Answer (score 1):

First converting from string to complex, you can then split the column into real and imaginary part. should be no problem to fit on both variables, since they are now of type float.

```
df['re'] = df.complex.map(lambda x: complex(x).real)
df['imag'] = df.complex.map(lambda x: complex(x).imag)
```

```
                                  complex        re      imag
0  -0.143704570332567-1.2618680524722614j -0.143705 -1.261868
```